# sql injection in php

Tags: php, mysql

my query written in php is:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM ".TABLE_PREFIX."login WHERE username ='".$username."' 
      AND password='".$password."'";
$res_id = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res_id);
echo $num_rows;
```

When i enter a valid user name and password from a form it works ok.

When i input some sql injection code the query output is:

```
SELECT * FROM form_login WHERE username ='' or '1'='1' AND password='' or '1'='1'
```

Which is a valid sql statement.But it gives an output(ie number of rows) as 0(zero).

If I write the same output sql statement in the program itself as-

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM form_login WHERE username ='' or '1'='1' 
   AND password='' or '1'='1'";
```

it works fine and it gives some result(for eg 3).

How can i get the correct result by inputing the sql injection code?

Comment: What is the exact text you are entering in the username and password boxes?

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing out the SQL statement. It may not be what you think it is, especially if `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled.

Comment: i  echoed the sql statement and my sql statement is as i have given in the question.
SELECT * FROM form_login WHERE username ='' or '1'='1' AND password='' or '1'='1' but the result is not comming.

Answer (score 1):

Or better yet, NEVER CONCATENATE SQL!

Try using the PDO library with [prepared sql statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Values are inherently safe in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

Before using any variable in a query, pass it through [mysql_real_escape_string](http://nl.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string).

Comment: I think in this case, he WANTS to have a SQL-Injection ;)

Comment: Not "any variable", but variable, enclosed in quotes only. So, there must be something for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter `' OR 1=1; --` *(note that space after -- )* into the username.
After that it doesn't matter what you enter into the password, because it will be commented out.

This will translate into the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM form_login WHERE username ='' or 1 = 1; -- AND password= 'whatever'
```